# Is there a better way to run a jar in development than running java -jar from the command line?

Tags: java, jar, automation, build-process, build-automation

I am working on a java dropwizard app, and to run it, I typically run

```
java -jar <my jar here>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to run this, and have it recognize that a new jar was created and start running that.  I can trigger a re-compile with a watch on the source files, but not sure how to get it to reload it.

Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: What does "and have it recognize that a new jar was created and start running that" mean? Really unclear about what you're asking here. Do you want some kind of... auto run after compilation? Or... are you trying to integrate ... something into some IDE you are using?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you run it like that on some server somewhere, and you're looking for a way to automatically restart it after you deploy a new version to the server? If that's the case can you give a bit more details about your server?

Comment: Yes, when I make a change, i can get it to mvn compile again, but the new jar is not loaded, I have to ctrl-C, and then re-run it, and would rather it some how notice the jar is new, and then run it.

Comment: This is for development, I am running it locally.

Comment: Well there isn't a *direct* way to do what you want (i.e. `java` itself doesn't have any built-in support for autorun-after-update like that), you'll have to automate it externally. I don't know how to use Maven but the simplest thing I can think of is to just write some shell script that kills the current run and starts a new one, and have your build system run that script after a build. Can Maven be set up to do that? Or perhaps use an IDE (like Eclipse or whatever) that has "run" functionality built right in to it, then you don't have to bother with Ctrl+C or typing the command.

Comment: Take a look at gradle for build automation.